# Limit exists theoritically,but graphically there is a vertical asymptote there.Why is it so.

Tags: calculus, limits

In finding the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}$
I used the substitution $x=2t$
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2^{2t}-1-2t}{4t^2}=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2^{2t}-2\times2^t+2\times2^t+1-2-2t}{t^2}$
$=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(2^{t}-1)^2+2\times2^t-2-2t}{t^2}$
$=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(2^{t}-1)^2}{t^2}+\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2^t-1-t}{t^2}$
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\ln2)^2$
But when i see the graph of the function,there is a vertical asymptote at $x=0$
And before $x=0$,function is approaching $\infty$ and after $x=0$,function is approaching $-\infty$.
That means limit should not exist,theoritically limit is coming but graphically limit does not exist.What is wrong?Why is it so?I do not understand.Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your mistake is that you used the limit laws wrongly. The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits **if the two separate limits exist**. Since you haven't proven that in your usage, and indeed it doesn't, the reasoning is flawed and hence does not contradict the actual fact that the limit does not exist.

Note also that you **cannot use L'Hopital's rule to prove that a limit does not exist**. Consider $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ and $g(x) = x$. Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ but $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is unbounded in any open neighbourhood of $0$, although $f(x),g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. So the non-existence of the limit after 'applying' L'Hopital's rule (ignoring the condition that the limit of the ratio of derivatives exists) **does not imply non-existence of the original limit**!

Comment: Thank you sir,i understood where i was wrong.@user21820

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: You're welcome. Also learn from Olivier's answer because it tells you how best to view such expressions and easily determine their limit or non-existence of limit and even tell you how it behaves. Here for example you see immediately that the graph is roughly a hyperbola plus a constant plus something that goes to zero as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Yep, or in other words, the converses of the usual limit laws and of L'Hospital's rules do not hold. E.g., functions such as $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ and $1-\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ can have their pathological parts cancel out (in this case, under multiplication or addition) and give well-behaved results, or, viewed alternatively, a well-behaved function can easily (just like in Paul Anderson's 'looked at the right way, anything is complicated' quote) be decomposed into ill-behaved ones. Nasty functions aren't closed under much (hence (one reason for) nasty), tying into the inability to deduce non-existence.

Answer (score 5):

There is a mistake in your steps.

Observe that, as $x \to 0$, by the Taylor expansion, one has
$$
e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}2+O(u^3)
$$ giving

> $$
> \frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{e^{x \ln 2}-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{-1+\ln 2}{x}+\frac{1}{2}(\ln2)^2+O(x)
> $$

which diverges as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}
$

For small $x$,
$2^x
=e^{x \ln 2}
\approx 1+x \ln 2+O(x^2)
$
so
$\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}
=\frac{1+x \ln 2 +O(x^2)-1-x}{x^2}
=\frac{x (\ln 2-1) +O(x^2)}{x^2}
=\frac{(\ln 2-1) +O(x)}{x}
\to \infty
$
as
$x \to 0$.

In general,
$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^x-1-x\ln a}{x^2}
$
exists
and is

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x \ln a}-1-x\ln a}{x^2}
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1+(x \ln a)+(x \ln a)^2/2+O(x^3)-1-x\ln a}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x \ln a)^2/2+O(x^3)}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}( \ln a)^2/2+O(x)\\
&=( \ln a)^2/2\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Since the original ratio is of the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, we use L'Hopital's rule:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x\ln{2}-1}{2x}=\frac{\ln{2}-1}{0}=\infty
$$

Thus the limit does not exist at $x=0$ and the vertical asymptote makes total sense.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is "why is this reasoning wrong?".

Comment: You already covered that.

Comment: But my substituting $x=2t$ and solving is also correct.Is it not?

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: It depends on what you mean by correct. I think you don't really know what it means. When you perform the substitution, what is correct is that **if the new limit exists, then the old one is equal**, but you still do not know whether it exists or not.

Comment: No. When you break up your single limit into 2 limits, you are assuming implicitly that the limit exists so that the breaking of the limit makes sense.

Comment: Also, Laars, you've to be careful with L'Hopital's rule. Your reasoning is actually flawed in the same way as the asker's. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule for the conditions that must hold, which do not hold in your usage.

Comment: In his above comment he's talking about the substitution step, which is correct in the sense I stated. The splitting of course is incorrect.

Comment: Furthermore, consider $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ and $g(x) = x$. Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ but $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is unbounded in any open neighbourhood of $0$. So the non-existence of the limit after 'applying' L'Hopital's rule **does not imply non-existence of the original limit**.

Comment: Let $f(x)=2^x-1-x$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Then both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on any closed interval that contains $0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$ and $g'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\ne 0$. All the conditions are met for L'Hopital's rule! EDIT: I forgot the existence of $f'/g'$. Clearly this is where I failed in the use.

Comment: @user21820, your example of $f(x)=x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ and $g(x)=x$ can be ignored, since $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $x \to 0$ is first of all not an indeterminate form, so there is no question of applying L'Hopital's Rule for Non indeterminate forms. For example $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}=0$  is obtained just by cancelling the power of $x$ and without cancelling and considering it as $\frac{0}{0}$ form and applying L'Hopital's rule is i donot think is necessary.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma: Err it is an indeterminate form since both numerator and denominator go to zero. Secondly, whether you can cancel or not means nothing to my objection, which is that it satisfies all conditions of L'Hopital's rule except the condition that the limit of ratio of derivatives exists, and yet the original limit exists. If you want an example where cancellation is not available, just use $g(x) = \sin(x)$ instead!